# How is this formula arrived at?

Tags: algorithms

I'm reading through Skiena's "The Algorithm Design Manual".

He analyses the number of copy operations performed in a dynamic array.

"Suppose we start with an array of size 1, and double its size from $m$ to $2m$ each time we run out of space. This doubling process involves allocating a new contiguous array of size $2m$, copying the contents of the old array into the lower half of the new one. The apparent waste is in the recopying of the old contents, on each expansion.

Skiena then asks:

"How many times might an element have to be recopied after a total of $n$ insertions?".

He then gives a formula for calculating the total number of movements $M$, for $n$ insertions.

$$\mathbf{M}=\sum_{i=1}^{\log n} i\cdot\frac{n}{2^i}$$

His explanation is:

"Well, the first inserted element will have been recopied when the array expands after the first, second, fourth, eighth, ...insertions. It will take $\log_{2}n$ doublings until the array gets to have n positions. However, most elements do not suffer much upheaval. Indeed, the $(n/2 + 1)$st through $n$th elements will move at most once and might never have to move at all."

But I really don't understand how he draws the formula from that. Can anyone help me understand how he reaches it?

Answer (score 0):

The total number of copies at each array size $n$ looks to me like it follows this table:

$$\begin{array}{ccccc} \lceil \log_2 n \rceil & n & \text{array size} & \text{copies on resize} & \text{total copies} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3-4 & 4 & 2 & 3\\
3 & 5-8 & 8 & 4 & 7 \\
4 & 9-16 & 16 & 8 & 15 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots &\vdots &\vdots \\
\lceil \log_2 n \rceil & n & 2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil} & 2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil-1} & 2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil}-1
\end{array}
$$

The formula for the total number of copies is evidently $$2^{\lceil \log_2 n \rceil} - 1.$$

I don't see a connection between this formula and the one you posted, without assuming typos or other errors.  Is he perhaps counting something other than the total number of copies?